# Strange behavior of headers with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Can you please let me know how to make the requests version below work like the urllib one? I have no idea what is going wrong. Effectively, the referer header is needed so that my request is not redirected to the home page. The urllib version seems to handle that properly and I can then download the file. This is not the case with the requests case which redirect to the home page. It seems that the referer header is not taken into account and I'm redirected to the home page.

Thanks

urllib version

```
import urllib.request
url = "http://www.truefx.com/dev/data/2017/MARCH-2017/EURUSD-2017-03.zip"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
request.add_header('Referer', 'http://www.truefx.com/')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
# Check for redirect
print("Final url:" + response.geturl())
print("Code: " + str(response.code))
print("File size: " + str(response.length))
```

Ouput:

```
> Final url:http://www.truefx.com/dev/data/2017/MARCH-2017/EURUSD-2017-03.zip
> Code: 200
> File size: 53041630
```

requests version

```
url = "http://www.truefx.com/dev/data/2017/MARCH-2017/EURUSD-2017-03.zip"
headers = {"referer": "http://www.truefx.com/?page=download"}
r = requests.get(url, headers)
print(r.url)
print(r.status_code)
```

Output:

```
http://www.truefx.com
200
```

Comment: You specified entirely different referrers in your two code snippets.

Comment: Also, you used `headers` as the query parameter dict, not the headers, in your `requests` code.

Comment: Thanks user2357112!

The difference in the referrer is not the problem but as you said my headers were not added successfully.

Replacing with:

r = requests. get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

headers dict was passed as a different argument. Replacing:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers)
```

with

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

solves the problem.